# Android ExpandListView - need an EditText to be displayed only at the end

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, expandablelistview

I need some help with Android ExpandListView.

My child view looks something like this :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggle"/>

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="Yes"
    android:textOff="No"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toggle"/>
```

I pass bunch of data to my adapter such as this :

```
    List<String> adapterData = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapterData.add("Example 1");
    adapterData.add("Example 2");
    adapterData.add("Example 3");
```

The issue is that currently my editText appears under every single TextView which is initialized with the adapter.

My requirement is that the editText should come only once at the end after all the rows (where every row has one TextView on the left and TottleButton on the right).

I tried doing this :

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       ...............

        if (childPosition ==3) {
        et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

       ..............
    }
```

}

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

if(groupPosition==(yourArrayList.size()-1) && isLastChild){

editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

put this code in  getChildView(...)  method of ExpandableListAdapter.
Edit: initially set visibility of EditText.setVisibility(INVISIBLE). When you expand the listview, ie, in the method where you have written the expansion of row, set EditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Comment: That's not correct man, in that case my editText would be outside of ExpandListView. I want that when I expand the list, the editText should come under the last TextView

Comment: ok, then check the last position array you pass to listview , you can get it in adapter class and then set visibility accordingly,

Comment: I did this :         if (childPosition == 3) {
            et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }  Now it has become visible at random points...